# How to run a function in PHP when MySQL table is modified (e.g adding a row)

Tags: php, mysql, live

I'm trying to make a system where PHP gets information from the newest row, and displays them live on the page. (think of messaging apps) I have everything down except the part where I need to add the information to the page when the table is updated. Can anybody help? (sorry if this isn't clear, this is my first time posting on stackoverflow)

Comment: This feels like it's mistaking how PHP works. A user requests a URL, the server knows that it's a route serviced by PHP, PHP _starts up_, runs the script(s) it needs to, and then _dies again_. What you're asking about only makes sense if PHP somehow "kept running", which it by design is never meant to do. Instead of having PHP get a signal, you just need to check the database state before generating the page content for some given page, when that page is requested. To get "live updates", either poll a separate URL just for that purpose, or set up a websocket connection and use that.

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this. You need to use periodic polling of the database.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, and barmar, appreciate both of your explanations. I'm still quite new to PHP so there are some concepts I don't fully understand

Comment: I agree, if you want to make  chat system it's probably a job for websockets. And php isn't great at those, to be honest. This may not be the ideal beginner project.